# First item in each - jQuery templates

Tags: jquery-templates

I'm trying do write a jQuery template where I loop over an array and the first element of the array produces a different output to the remaining elements

```
<script type='text/x-jquery-tmpl'>
  {{each things}}
    {{if ${index} == 0}}
      <div class='active'>${value}</div>
    {{else}}
      <div class='passive'>${value}</div>
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

and data:

```
{things: ["Val1", "Val2", ... , "Valn"]}
```

But the `{{if ${index} == 0}}` condition does not work. How do I make the template produce a different output for the first item of the array from the rest?

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove curly braces at ${index}

```
{{if $index == 0}}
```